# An error while executing a PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am actually developing a function in postgres. I'm using some traces to gather information from this one. I'm trying this piece of code that made me stuck somehow, and your help will make it easier to me.

```
    --For Month-Year, we subtract the last part so we could have only "Month"    
V_SQL_QRY := 'UPDATE ZONE AS ZN '||
                            'SET '||V_CAT_DMOIS||' = regexp_replace(EC.OCCURRENCE, ''\-[0-9]{4}'',''''), ' 
                        ||V_CAT_ANNEE||' = SUBSTRING(EC.OCCURRENCE FROM ''....$''), '
                              ||V_CAT_DM||' = ROUND(EC.MONTANT_BASE::numeric, 2) '|| 
                       'FROM ECHEANCE AS EC '||
                          'WHERE '||V_ZONE_C||' AND ZN.UNID = EC.ZONE_ID AND EC.CANEVAS_ID = '||V_TAX_ID||' AND EC.ETAT = ''P'' '||
                            'AND SUBSTRING(EC.OCCURRENCE FROM ''....$'')||convertmonth(regexp_replace(EC.OCCURRENCE,''\-[0-9]{4}'','''')) '||
                            '= (SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(EH.OCCURRENCE FROM ''....$'')||convertmonth(regexp_replace(EH.OCCURRENCE,''\-[0-9]{4}'','''')) '|| 
                             'FROM ECHEANCE AS EH '||
                            'WHERE EH.ZONE_ID = EC.ZONE_ID AND EH.CANEVAS_ID = EC.CANEVAS_ID AND EH.ETAT = ''P'') '||
                        'AND NOT ( '||V_CAT_DMOIS||' IS NOT NULL '||
                        'AND '||V_CAT_ANNEE||' IS NOT NULL AND ' ||V_CAT_ANNEE||' SIMILAR TO ''\d{4}'' '||
                            'AND '||V_CAT_DM||' IS NOT NULL AND '||V_CAT_DM||' SIMILAR TO ''[\d\s]+[.]?\d*'' '|| -- On considère le montant avec '.' au lieu de la ','
                            'AND CAST(FORMAT('||V_CAT_DM||') AS DOUBLE PRECISION) > 0 '||
                            'AND '||V_CAT_ANNEE||' > EC.ANNEE_REFERENCE '||
                                'OR '||V_CAT_ANNEE||' = EC.ANNEE_REFERENCE '||
                               'AND convertmonth('||V_CAT_DMOIS||') > convertmonth(regexp_replace(EH.OCCURRENCE,''-[0-9]{4}'',''''))))';
                    EXECUTE V_SQL_QRY;
```

When executing it for the test, the traces table gave me the next error :

```
SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRM=Syntax Error Near "FROM"
```

I'd be grateful for your help

Comment: If you are using Postgres you can't be using `PL/SQL` because that's Oracle only. Please show us the **complete** function code and how you run it.

Comment: You should be using a prepared statement (using place holders) anyway rather then concatenating all values into one giant string (and then `format()` would be better in Postgres)

Comment: In fact, it's PLPGSQL since it's concerning Postgres

the function is too long(about 400 lines) , I just posted the part that makes problem in my function.

I'm trying right now to make it more simple, for Postgres as for me. any results will be shared. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code is absolutely unreadable. Good help in this case is using `RAISE NOTICE '%', V_SQL_QRY;` before execution. When the dynamic string is complex, then function `format` and custom string separators helps:

```
EXECUTE format($str$ UPDATE foo SET %I='AHOJ' $str$, column_name)
```